# Adding datatable for two words id

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table with `id ='home_approval request'`.I want to add datatable using this id .
    Its working if `id='approval'`. Now datatable is not working for two word id separated by space

```
var table_home = $('#home_approval').DataTable();
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#home_approval').DataTable();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<table id="home_approval request" class="display" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
      <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>$433,060</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sonya Frost</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>$103,600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
      <td>Support Lead</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>$342,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Dai Rios</td>
      <td>Personnel Lead</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>35</td>
      <td>$217,500</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The issue is because you cannot have spaces in an `id`. Remove them.

Comment: You can have more informations about `id` here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_id.asp

Comment: @ Rory McCrossan in html or in jquery

Comment: HTML, and therefore jQuery and Javascript too by proxy.

Comment: `id` can not have spaces in between words/letters (IN HTML). as well cannot used in jquery too. If you want spaces then use `class`

Answer (score -2):

As mentioned on  [w3c](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_id.asp) `id` attribute must not contain white-spaces.

> Tip: The id attribute can be used on any HTML element.
>
> Note: The id value is case-sensitive.
>
> Note: The id value must contain at least one character, and must not
>   contain whitespace (spaces, tabs, etc.).